# What exactly is the difference between SDN & NFV?

Tags: sdn, nfv

What is the difference between SDN (Software Defined Networking) & NFV (Network Function Virtualization)?  Wikipedia says NFV relies on standard client-server model. How is this model different than Data plane-Controller plane model?

Please explain it with an example if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree with the answer provided @Pedro Perez, I think his answer is mixing phrases and ambiguous so I have provided my own interpretation below.

**SDN:**
I think it is pretty much what the name says “Software Defined Networking”. This means to me that software is defining the paths that packets take across the network automatically (possibly with some upper bound / lower bound constraints provided by a human operator). It can also readjust paths automatically that are within those predefined constraints. I would consider a deployment that uses an off-box (centralised) control plane such as the OpenDaylight SDN controller with protocols such as Open Flow, BGP-LS or PCEP to be an SDN deployment. The SDN controller is talking to network devices and steering traffic based on live data it receives from the network devices.

**NFV:**

Again pretty much what the acronym suggests “Network Function Virtualisation”. This to me is about virtualising network functions – not how devices forward packets and make decisions (which is covered by SDN) but at the device level how one can virtualise and containerise network functions so that they may be rapidly deployed, re-replayed, migrated, decommissioned etc. To clarify a network function here would be say NAT, CG-NAT, ACLs, QoS, tunnelling, DNS or web filtering, load-balancing etc. I would consider a deployment that uses standard computing hardware (such as x86 servers for example) to run virtual machines or containers that are routers, switches, firewalls load balancers etc. to be an NFV deployment. With NFV one can chain multiple virtual functions together to form a service chain.  For example running multiples virtual machines on a single x86 box that forms a pipeline and a packet must pass through the entire VM pipeline; the first VM could be a virtual switch and faces an office LAN, if the packet is destine to the Internet it could hand over to a virtual firewall, if the packet passes the firewall rules it can hand over to a virtual router, which can then send the packet out of a physical WAN link.

**NSO/LSO:**

“Network Service Orchestration” or “Lifecycle Service Orchestration” have an overlapping definition in my opinion regarding the (usually) automated process of applying changes to network devices, configuration and infrastructure and managing the infrastructure such as deployment, upgrades, decommissioning etc. I am bringing this up because a NFV based network can be completely deployed by hand; you might be using KVM on Linux and you SSH in to each KVM machine and start up virtual router images from the likes of Juniper and Cisco by hand, on the CLI using `virsh` for example. It could also be VMware using ESXi and again you use the web console to do everything (these are just common examples). You are still virtualising network functions and potentially chaining them together if required, just slowly and potentially erroneously by hand. With SDN one could be using BGP-LS with an off box controller to automatically steer traffic flows around the network which could be built using physical routers (the traditional infrastructure build method), but the controller could also be controlling traffic flows on virtual routers (an NFV based infrastructure), SDN is agnostic of whether the devices are physical or virtual or just two bean cans and some string and an API layer above them.

NSO/LSO approaches to network operations have existing for years, but not with the formal guidance that they have now (such as through the MEF LSO (Metro Ethernet Forum) standards). In its most basic form, engineers have been writing scripts that telnet or SSH to a device and apply commands via the CLI. If one expands that basic example a bit further to have scripts that automatically apply bits of config to devices vi the CLI, TFTP boot new firmware versions on devices, generate config files from templates, which is all stuff people have been doing for years, then we have an informal NSO/LSO platform.

I hope that has made it clear that NSO/LSO is different from NFV and SDN, they are three concepts that can all exist without the other two or be used in any combination with the other two.

**Side note about network overlays, virtual networking and network virtualisation:**

> @Pedro Perez mentioned: Completely abstract the physical network and
>   use it as a resource pool for virtual (overlay?) networking so to
>   speak.

Virtual networking and network virtualisation are two different things in my opinion. Firstly to take a step back, there are some protocols that provide what I would call a network overlay such as VXLAN, NVGRE and STT (which in turn use transport protocols like MPLS, or IP in IP etc.). Those overlay protocols alone though don’t provide a virtualised network, they transport traffic across the network, but we also need support for network functions or services within the overlay network (such as NAT, QoS, ACLs, maybe traffic steering like TE etc.), also some amount of administration and management is required, reporting and quality control and so on. Once we have all of that then I would say we have a virtual network offering (“virtual networking”).

We consider virtual servers to be servers that run on top of physical servers (let’s forget about nested virtualisation/nested hypervisors for the moment!).  Above I defined what I consider a virtual network which runs over a “real” network which would have traditionally been physical tin. One example could be that as an ISP one can deliver a virtual network to a customer in the form of MPLS L3 VPNs (L3 IP VPNs using VRFs/RTs/RDs as the overlay model, MPLS for the transport protocol, MP-BGPv4 for the control plane and MPLS OAM for some operational management). This would run over a physical network that supports MPLS as a transport protocol.

For the definition of network virtualisation, I would refer back to the NFV section above. So to go full circle; in this ISP example, if our customer offing is a virtual networking and if we run our backbone network as an NFV based deployment, then I would say we are offering virtual networking over our network virtualisation deployment. Clear as mud.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Ok, I'm going to get into trouble as there's always a lot of discussion around SDN and NFV concepts, so please take my answer with a pinch of salt. Your views might differ and we both might be right or wrong :)

I see SDN as two things, depending on who you ask:

1. Ability to automate / orchestrate your physical network.
2. Completely abstract the physical network and use it as a resource pool for virtual (overlay?) networking so to speak. Then apply the previous automation / orchestration point of course.

NFV is more focused on extracting the value proposition of a networking product and virtualising it.

NFV does not often have a place on #1 above, because we're just orchestrating a physical network and automating changes. We are not virtualising any function.

On #2 NFV makes more sense. I like to illustrate this with the "firewall" example as it is easy to visualize. On most networks you'd like to have some visibility and control over your traffic, so you strategically place a firewall appliance (or a pair in HA) and make sure the traffic has to go through it; then you deploy your favourite firewall rules and enable logging for a bunch of them, too.

On a virtualised network you can still deploy a VM running the same firewall software and mimic your physical network deployments, but why don't go a step further and virtualise the firewall function and not the product itself?

All your virtual networking traffic already goes through virtual switches. These virtual switches reside on all your physical hosts. [Why don't we deploy those firewall rules directly on the virtual switch?](https://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli-nova-configure-access-security-for-instances.html) This way you are virtualising the firewall function and distributing the cost of controlling traffic among your infrastructure, thus having a more predictable cost of scaling (i.e. your firewall capabilities increase with your computing capabilities).

So it's not about the management model of each, it is about the purpose of each of them. There's overlapping between the both and SDN is definitely an enabled for NFV.

Answer (score 1):

NFV aims at decoupling NFs from specialized hardware elements while SDN
focuses on separating the handling of packets and connections from overall
network control.

In the SDN architecture, virtualization is the allocation of abstract
resources to particular clients or applications; in NFV, the goal is to abstract NFs away from dedicated hardware, for example to allow them to be
hosted on server platforms in cloud data centers

NFV can work on existing networks because it resides on servers and interacts with specific traffic sent to them, SDN requires a new network construct where the data and control planes are separate

Answer (score 0):

**SDN**

In SDN enabled network there will be a controller (different controllers POX, RYU, OPENDAYLIGHT,FLOODLIGHT) and this controller will have knowledge of the entire network elements and also knows the real time traffic information. This knowledge can be used to perform real time traffic engineering.

**NFV**

With help of NFV we can implement network elements in software instead of 
dedicated hardware.
Eg. we can run **click programs(click modular router)** to impliment network elemets like load balencer in open-flow switch instead of dedicated hardware